# How do I upload my code for a new mediawiki extension?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to create a new MediaWiki extention. 
How do I put my code on the extension page so users can download it?

Comment: What “extension page” are you talking about? Could you include a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the instructions here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Extensions#Extension_authors

Comment: I see the info on how to create an edit the page for a new extension but I'm not clear where to add the code for a the extension files.

Comment: Github, or you can get a Gerrit account and become the maintainer for it there.